# how 'sequences' parameter works in theano scan function

Tags: theano, theano.scan

In prior to get to the point, I apologize for my English sentences that can be rather awkward. Because English is not my first language.

Now I am struggle with using theano.tensor.scan function properly. But, I don’t know how ‘sequences parameter’ works. 
I created 3 dimensional array (42,10,7002) and input as sequences. I expect the unit of sequences would be 2 dimensional array (10,7002) and the number of steps would be 42. 
But it seems like unit of sequences is (1,7002) how can I handle unit of sequences that should be row 10 and column 7002 ?
thanks for reading this question.

- add

> ```
> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
>
> __author__ = "Haizhou Qu"
>
> import readFile
> import numpy as np
> import theano
> import theano.tensor as T
> from six.moves import zip
> # from theano.compile.debugmode import DebugMode
>
> theano.config.optimizer='fast_compile'
> theano.config.exception_verbosity='high'
> theano.config.compute_test_value = 'warn'
>
> epsilon = 1e-6
> dtype = theano.config.floatX
> minibatch_size_g = 0
> longest_seq_g = 0
> voca_dim_global = 0
> n_time_step_input_g = 0
> n_timestep_target_g = 0
>
>
> def printT(x):
>     t = theano.printing.Print('T')(x)
>     return t
>
> def shared(value, name=None):
>     return theano.shared(value.astype(dtype), name=name)
>
>
> def shared_zeros(shape, name=None):
>     return shared(value=np.zeros(shape), name=name)
>
>
> def shared_zeros_like(x, name=None):
>     return shared_zeros(shape=x.shape, name=name)
>
>
> def init_weights(shape, name=None):
>     bound = np.sqrt(1.0/shape[1])
>     w = np.random.uniform(-bound, bound, shape)
>     return shared(value=w, name=name)
>
>
> def adadelta(params, cost, lr=1.0, rho=0.95):
>     # from https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py
>     cost = cost.astype('float32')
>     grads = T.grad(cost, params)
>     accus = [shared_zeros_like(p.get_value()) for p in params]
>     delta_accus = [shared_zeros_like(p.get_value()) for p in params]
>     updates = []
>     for p, g, a, d_a in zip(params, grads, accus, delta_accus):
>         new_a = rho * a + (1.0 - rho) * T.square(g)
>         updates.append((a, new_a))
>         update = g * T.sqrt(d_a + epsilon) / T.sqrt(new_a + epsilon)
>         new_p = p - lr * update
>         updates.append((p, new_p))
>         new_d_a = rho * d_a + (1.0 - rho) * T.square(update)
>         updates.append((d_a, new_d_a))
>     return updates
>
>
> def categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
>     # from https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/objectives.py
>     y_pred = T.clip(y_pred, epsilon, 1.0 - epsilon)
>
>     y_pred = y_true.astype('int64')
>     # only matrix can be calculated
>     cce, updates = theano.scan(
>   fn=T.nnet.categorical_crossentropy,   
>         sequences=[y_pred,y_true]
>   )
>     cce.astype('float32')
>     return T.mean(cce)
>
>
> def mean_square_error(y_true, y_pred):
>     return T.mean(T.square(y_pred - y_true))
>
>
> class LSTM(object):
>     def __init__(self, size, dim):
>         self.size = size
>         self.dim = dim
>
>         shape_b = (minibatch_size_g, size)
>         shape_U = (dim, size)
>         shape_W = (size, size)
>
>         self.h_tm1 = shared_zeros(shape_b, "h_tm1")
>         self.c_tm1 = shared_zeros(shape_b, "c_tm1")
>
>         self.Ui = init_weights(shape_U, "Ui")
>         self.Wi = init_weights(shape_W, "Wi")
>         self.bi = shared_zeros(shape_b, "bi")
>
>         self.Uf = init_weights(shape_U, "Uf")
>         self.Wf = init_weights(shape_W, "Wf")
>         self.bf = shared_zeros(shape_b, "bf")
>
>         self.Uo = init_weights(shape_U, "Uo")
>         self.Wo = init_weights(shape_W, "Wo")
>         self.bo = shared_zeros(shape_b, "bo")
>
>         self.Ug = init_weights(shape_U, "Ug")
>         self.Wg = init_weights(shape_W, "Wg")
>         self.bg = shared_zeros(shape_b, "bg")
>
>         self.params = [
>             self.Ui, self.Wi, self.bi,
>             self.Uf, self.Wf, self.bf,
>             self.Uo, self.Wo, self.bo,
>             self.Ug, self.Wg, self.bg
>         ]
>
>     def set_state(self, h, c):
>         self.h_tm1.set_value(h.get_value())
>         self.c_tm1.set_value(c.get_value())
>
>     def reset_state(self):
>         self.h_tm1 = shared_zeros((1, self.size), "h_tm1")
>         self.c_tm1 = shared_zeros((1, self.size), "c_tm1")
>
>
>
>
>     @staticmethod
>     def step(
>         x_t, h_tm1, c_tm1,
>         Ui, Wi, bi, Uf, Wf, bf,
>         Uo, Wo, bo, Ug, Wg, bg
>     ):
>
>         """
>         x_t.shape = (timestep=1, dim)
>         x_t.shape = (n_samples, timestep=1, dim)
>         """
>         # x_t.eval().shape
>         x_t = x_t.reshape( (minibatch_size_g , -1) )
>         #x_t = x_t.reshape( (voca_dim_global , -1) )
>
>
>         h_tm1 = h_tm1.reshape( (-1, n_time_step_input_g)    )
>         c_tm1 = c_tm1.reshape( (-1, n_time_step_input_g)    )
>
>         i_t = T.nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(x_t, Ui) + T.dot(h_tm1, Wi) + bi)
>
>         a=T.dot(x_t, Uf)
>         b=T.dot(h_tm1, Wf)
>         c=a+b
>         f_t=c+bf
>         #f_t = T.nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(x_t, Uf) + T.dot(h_tm1, Wf) + bf)
>
>
>         o_t = T.nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(x_t, Uo) + T.dot(h_tm1, Wo) + bo)
>         g_t = T.tanh(T.dot(x_t, Ug) + T.dot(h_tm1, Wg) + bg)
>
>         c_t = c_tm1 * f_t + g_t * i_t
>         h_t = T.tanh(c_t) * o_t
>
>         #c_t = c_t.reshape( (1, -1) )
>         #h_t = h_t.reshape( (1, -1) )
>
>         return h_t, c_t
>
>
>
>     def forward(self, X):
>         """
>         X.shape = (timesteps, dim)
>         X.shape = (n_samples, timesteps, dim)        
>         """
>
>         X = X.reshape( (-1, voca_dim_global * minibatch_size_g) ) 
>
>         states, updates = theano.scan(
>             fn=self.step,
>             sequences=[  X  ],
>             outputs_info=[self.h_tm1, self.c_tm1],
>             non_sequences=[
>                 self.Ui, self.Wi, self.bi,
>                 self.Uf, self.Wf, self.bf,
>                 self.Uo, self.Wo, self.bo,
>                 self.Ug, self.Wg, self.bg
>             ]
>         )
>
>         updates = [(self.h_tm1, states[0][-1]), (self.c_tm1, states[1][-1])]
>         print("### forward completed ###")
>         return states, updates
>
>
> class LSTMEncoder(LSTM):
>     def encode(self, X):
>         states, updates = self.forward(X)
>         h_t = states[0][-1]
>         c_t = states[1][-1]
>         return h_t, c_t, updates
>
>
> class LSTMDecoder(LSTM):
>     def __init__(self, size, dim, h_tm1=None, c_tm1=None):
>         super(LSTMDecoder, self).__init__(size=size, dim=dim)
>         self.Wh = init_weights((size, dim), "Wh")
>         self.bh = shared_zeros((1, dim), "bh")
>
>         self.h_tm1 = h_tm1 or shared_zeros((1, size), "h_tm1")
>         self.c_tm1 = c_tm1 or shared_zeros((1, size), "c_tm1")
>
>         self.y_t = shared_zeros((1, dim), "y_t")
>
>         # self.decode_length = theano.shared(decode_length)
>
>         self.params.append(self.Wh)
>         self.params.append(self.bh)
>
>     def decode_step(
>         self, y_t, h_tm1, c_tm1,
>         Ui, Wi, bi, Uf, Wf, bf,
>         Uo, Wo, bo, Ug, Wg, bg,
>         Wh, bh
>     ):
>         h_t, c_t = self.step(
>             y_t, h_tm1, c_tm1,
>             Ui, Wi, bi, Uf, Wf, bf,
>             Uo, Wo, bo, Ug, Wg, bg
>         )
>         y_t = T.dot(h_t, Wh) + bh
>         return y_t, h_t, c_t
>
>     def decode(self, h_tm1, c_tm1, timesteps):
>         outputs, updates = theano.scan(
>             fn=self.decode_step,
>             outputs_info=[self.y_t, h_tm1, c_tm1],
>             non_sequences=[
>                 self.Ui, self.Wi, self.bi,
>                 self.Uf, self.Wf, self.bf,
>                 self.Uo, self.Wo, self.bo,
>                 self.Ug, self.Wg, self.bg,
>                 self.Wh, self.bh
>             ],
>             n_steps=timesteps
>         )
>         updates = [
>             (self.h_tm1, outputs[1][-1]),
>             (self.c_tm1, outputs[2][-1])
>         ]
>         return T.flatten(outputs[0], 2), updates
>
>
> class Seq2Seq(object):
>     def __init__(self, size, dim):
>         self.encoder = LSTMEncoder(size, dim)
>         self.decoder = LSTMDecoder(size, dim)
>         self.params = []
>         self.params += self.encoder.params
>         self.params += self.decoder.params
>         self._predict = None
>         self._train = None
>         self._test = None
>
>     def compile(self, loss_func, optimizer):
>         seq_input = T.tensor3()
>         seq_target = T.tensor3()
>         decode_timesteps = T.iscalar()
>
>         h_tm1, c_tm1, updates_encode = self.encoder.encode(seq_input)
>         seq_predict_flex, updates_decode_flex = self.decoder.decode(h_tm1, c_tm1, decode_timesteps)
>         seq_predict, updates_decode = self.decoder.decode(h_tm1, c_tm1, T.shape(seq_target)[0])
>
>         loss = loss_func(seq_predict, seq_target)
>         self._predict = theano.function([seq_input, decode_timesteps], seq_predict_flex,
> ```
>
> updates=updates_encode+updates_decode_flex)
>               self._test = theano.function([seq_input, seq_target], loss, updates=updates_encode+updates_decode)
>               updates = []
>               updates += updates_encode
>               updates += updates_decode
>               updates += optimizer(self.params, loss)
>               self._train = theano.function([seq_input, seq_target], loss, updates=updates)
>
> ```
>     def predict(self, seq_input, decode_timesteps):
>         self.encoder.reset_state()
>         self.decoder.reset_state()
>         return self._predict(seq_input, decode_timesteps)
>
>     def train(self, seq_input, seq_target):
>         self.encoder.reset_state()
>         self.decoder.reset_state()
>         return self._train(seq_input, seq_target)
>
>     def test(self, seq_input, seq_target):
>         self.encoder.reset_state()
>         self.decoder.reset_state()
>         return self._test(seq_input, seq_target)
>
>
> def train(x, target):
>     for mini_batch, target in zip(x,target):
>         print("mini_batch shape :",mini_batch.shape)
>
>         mini_batch = mini_batch.astype(dtype)
>         target = target.astype(dtype)
>
>         print(seq2seq.train(mini_batch, target))
>
>
> def predict(x, target):
>     for mini_batch, target in zip(x,target):
>         so = seq2seq.predict(x, n_time_step_output_g)
>         print(so)
>         loss = seq2seq.test(x, so)
>         print(loss)
>
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>
>     si, st, maxlen_input, minibatch_size, voca_dim = readFile.preprocessing()
>
>     voca_dim_global = voca_dim + 2
>     minibatch_size_g = si[0].shape[1]
>
>     print("minibatch_size_g : " , 10)
>     print("minibatch_size_g : " , si[0].shape[1])
>
>     n_time_step_input_g = si[0].shape[0]
>     n_time_step_output_g = st[0].shape[0]
>
>     seq2seq = Seq2Seq(n_time_step_input_g, voca_dim_global )
>     seq2seq.compile(loss_func=categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=adadelta)
>
>     print("select a menu")
>     print("1. Training")
>     print("2. Predict and test translated sentence.")
>     val = input("selection : ") 
>
>     if val == 1:
>         train(si, st)
>
>     elif val == 2:
>         predict(si, st)
> ```

Comment: scan always iterates over the 1st dimension of tensor (i.e for 42 steps), so on each iteration you should get (10, 7002). Can you post your complete code ?

Comment: uyaseen, thank you for interest in my question. For now, I added the whole code, but it is hard to understand it (for me, It takes over two weeks).

Comment: input dimension is (27,10,7002)

Comment: 1/2 The code is a bit cumbersome to go through (also I do not have data + pre-processing files), [this](https://github.com/mila-udem/summerschool2015/blob/master/scan_tutorial/scan_tutorial.ipynb) is a nice tutorial on scan. Since it's an encoder-decoder framework on textual data you need to iterate over words (and to do it efficiently you need to use mini-batches), 3rd dimension being 7002 looks odd btw, what does it represent ? but 1st dimension should normally represent mini-batches (or sequence length if you are not using mini-batches) in either case you need to use

Comment: 2/2 [dimshuffle(..)](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor._tensor_py_operators.dimshuffle) to adjust such that 1st dimension represents words. Here is a an example of [Sequence to Sequence](https://github.com/uyaseen/neural-converse) in Theano.

Comment: I am using mini-batchs. 7002 is one-hot vector representation (word_dimensions, the number of words appear in whole sentences) ,10 is minibatch_size(I wanted10 sentences are processed simultaneously), and 27 is step_number. I intended 27 iteration on step function, and each words in 10 sentences are intended to be processed simultaneously. by the way, I really thankful your answer. I really have not had the person who help me. You are the first person

Comment: I see. Since you first dimension is already the words, you don't need to use `dimshuffle(..)`. Also, because of `reshape(..)` on `X` in your `forward()` method before scan you are getting `(1, 7002)` (I am not sure if it is the right thing to do).

Comment: uyaseen, Thank you for your advice. I solved this problem anyway. But I confused the problem because I misunderstand debugging message. It is hard to understand theano debugging message. if I understood it, every problem about theano might be easy.. anyway, I appreciate your help. I will remember you.